# Static block not working properly in magento

Tags: php, html, magento, static, block

I am using this code as to call phtml file in static block, but it is not working:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

anyone can give me a solution ???

Comment: Have you included the static block on a CMS page? Also have you cleared the caches?

Comment: What is 'not working"? do you have an error? some logs?

Comment: have you tried giving permission to  that new static block?

Comment: yes i have cleared all the caches and also i dont have any errors

Comment: Is the cms block set to display on the store you're looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento CE 1.9.2.2 includes all the changes from the [recent-patch](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788), one of which was restrict the blocks that can be used in CMS blocks, pages, emails (etc...) by default.

You can whitelist additional blocks through the admin under `System > Permissions > (Blocks | Variables)`

Comment: You are welcome @raw_hitt... If you find this answer is helpful, please accept the answer, so it will be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

include the static block on a CMS page and Also clear the caches and reindex the data